# How to config redis-cluster when use spring-data-redis

Tags: spring-session, spring-data-redis

I try to use Spring Session and Redis Cluster but get the error like 
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool.

But, if I use Jedis Client only, it connects successfully. Meanwhile, sentinel connection also works.

My application.yml looks like:

```
spring.redis.cluster:    --Can not connect

    nodes: 10.161.34.185:5000,10.161.34.186:5001,10.161.34.187:5002

#spring.redis.sentinel:  --Can connect
#    master: master01
#    nodes: 10.162.14.121:5000,10.162.14.122:5000
```

### My POM File is

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RC2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Redis Clustser Info:

```
redis_version:3.0.7
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:270ecdbb5d94abe
redis_mode:cluster
os:Linux 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.4.7
tcp_port:5000
hz:10
lru_clock:2032968
config_file:/apps/redis-essentials/redis-3.0.7/redis-master-01.conf
```

Comment: please provide more information on cluster configuration (redis-version) as well as the the full stacktrace.

Comment: Redis Cluster auto-configuration using Spring Boot is available since Spring Boot 1.4. Spring Boot 1.3.x supports only Redis Sentinel auto-configuration.